# Query ran on linked servers - different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 linked servers (SQL Server 2014), let's call them `LinkedServer1` and `LinkedServer2`.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT  
    Id, MyType
FROM    
    Table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    LinkedServer2.MyDataBase2.dbo.Table2 my ON a.Id = my.Id
                                            AND a.MyType = my.MyType
WHERE   
    a.MyType LIKE 'Test%'
    AND my.ContactId IS NULL
```

on `LinkedServer1`, I get 4 rows.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT  
    Id, MyType
FROM    
    LinkedServer1.MyDataBase1.dbo.Table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.Table2 my ON a.Id = my.Id
                  AND a.MyType = my.MyType
WHERE   
    a.MyType LIKE 'Test%'
    AND my.ContactId IS NULL
```

on `LinkedServer2`, I get 50 rows.

What is even weirder is if I keep running query 1 sometimes I get 0 rows and sometimes 4...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using LEFT OUTER JOIN-s, meaning that if tables hold different data you would get different results based on that.

Comment: but I am using the same tables, in the same orders, only the server where the query is run is different...

Comment: So I'm not sure why you're getting different results, but it probably has to do with SQL trying to run a test locally instead of remotely.  However, the bigger issue is it looks like you're just trying to check for existence -- try refactoring your query to be something like `SELECT c1, c2 FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.c1=b.c1 AND a.c2=b.c2) AND a.c1 LIKE 'Test%'`

Comment: I suppose your servers could have different default settings for something like default collation.  So, one server might be case sensitive and the other case insensitive.

Comment: Running the query on LinkedServer2 , returns same number of rows on both versions (the left outer join and the not exists) = 89. Running it on LinkedServer1, the left outer join returns 92 rows while the not exists version returns 111 rows...

Comment: Both servers have the same collation and collation compatibility is set to false on both linked servers...

Comment: Is it possible your data is so volatile it can be changing between runs?

Comment: No, it's a dev server and I am the only developer using those databases...

Comment: @OanaMarina, you have columns Id and MyType in both tables. Does your query run without errors when you select Id, MyType without specification the source table?

Comment: I don't understand how I can not specify the table, it's normal it won't run.. If I just select count(1) and not the columns I get the same behavior, number of rows is different. If I select everything from the linked server table into a temp table and then join with the temp table it's even worse, every run of the query produces different number of rows...